# Can't use Gems in Ruby C Extension unless i use full path

Tags: c, ruby, api, rubygems

Whenever I try to use a gem using Ruby's C API (with rb_require), I get a "cannot load such file --" error UNLESS i use the full path.  Requiring gems work fine in regular ruby scripts. Is these something else I need to do?  These gems are installed using Bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `rb_require` from an extension you are calling the core “built-in” process for requiring files in Ruby. This bypasses the Gem handling code that is added by Rubygems when it replaces the `Kernel#require` method.

In order to get the proper gem handling you need to call the normal `require` method and let the usual method dispatch route the call to the Rubygems code. You can do that with:

```
rb_funcall(rb_cObject, rb_intern("require"), 1, rb_str_new_cstr("the_gem"));
```

You could call `rb_intern` once and store the result to avoid calling it multiple times if you wanted.